# Launch gives a compliation error in Kotlin

Tags: kotlin, kotlin-coroutines

I was trying out a few things in Kotlin. The launch in the following code gives a compilation error. However, the `GlobalScope.launch` works and giving launch inside `runBlocking` also work.

```
 fun main() {
    launch{

    } }
```

Comment: It's impossible for such functions because it doesn't implement CoroutineScope

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you see the definition of the [launch](https://kotlin.github.io/kotlinx.coroutines/kotlinx-coroutines-core/kotlinx.coroutines/launch.html):

```kotlin
fun CoroutineScope.launch(
    context: CoroutineContext = EmptyCoroutineContext,
    start: CoroutineStart = CoroutineStart.DEFAULT,
    block: suspend CoroutineScope.() -> Unit
): Job (source)
```

It is an extension function to the [CoroutineScope](https://kotlin.github.io/kotlinx.coroutines/kotlinx-coroutines-core/kotlinx.coroutines/-coroutine-scope/index.html), so it must be called on a CoroutineScope.

If you use the runBlocking, it'll give you a CoroutineScope as `this` variable in the block, so `launch` implicitly is `this.launch`.

In order to launch a coroutine it must have a lifecycle [Job](https://kotlin.github.io/kotlinx.coroutines/kotlinx-coroutines-core/kotlinx.coroutines/-job/) and a [CoroutineDispatcher](https://kotlin.github.io/kotlinx.coroutines/kotlinx-coroutines-core/kotlinx.coroutines/-coroutine-dispatcher/), which is contained in the [CoroutineContext](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.coroutines/-coroutine-context/) inside the CoroutineScope.

So if you want the coroutine, there is two common practise:

1. runBlocking (single-threaded start).

   ```kotlin
   fun main() = runBlocking {  // this: CoroutineScope
       launch {}  // implicit this.launch {}
   }
   ```
2. coroutineScope factory function (starts at main thread but switches to default dispatcher when needed).

   ```kotlin
   suspend fun main() = coroutineScope {  // this: CoroutineScope
       launch {}  // implicit this.launch {}
   }
   ```